# Python while loop breaking after one iteration

Tags: python, while-loop

```py
inp = (input("Paste in the encoded message (over 100 words):\n")).lower()
inp_list = list(inp)
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
letter_counter = 26
new_list = []
number_of_es = []


def shift_list(lista):
    for item in lista:
        if item in letters:
            if (letters.index(item) - 1) < 0:
                position = (letters.index(item) - 1) + 26
            else:
                position = (letters.index(item) - 1)
            new_list.append(letters[position])
        else:
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list

while letter_counter > 0:
    number_of_es.append(inp_list.count("e"))
    print(number_of_es)
    letter_counter -= 1
    inp_list = shift_list(inp_list)
    print(inp_list)
    print(letter_counter)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuGrp.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6oE4.png)

I am a beginner in python but have started trying to write some code that I find interesting. I am trying to make a program that cycles each letter in a line of text through the alphabet, counting the incidences of the letter 'e'.

The problem I am having is that the while loop seems to break after one iteration and I can't see where the problem is.

Comment: could you post your code as text?

Answer (score 0):

Python provides two keywords that terminate a loop iteration prematurely:

The Python break statement immediately terminates a loop entirely. Program execution proceeds to the first statement following the loop body.

The Python continue statement immediately terminates the current loop iteration. Execution jumps to the top of the loop, and the controlling expression is re-evaluated to determine whether the loop will execute again or terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the `new_list` within the function `shift_list()` should fix the problem.

Thus a new empty list is created and filled for each function call.
Otherwise the list is always extended because it was a global variable.

```py
inp = (input("Paste in the encoded message (over 100 words):\n")).lower()
inp_list = list(inp)
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
letter_counter = 26
number_of_es = []


def shift_list(lista):
    new_list = []
    for item in lista:
        if item in letters:
            if (letters.index(item) - 1) < 0:
                position = (letters.index(item) - 1) + 26
            else:
                position = (letters.index(item) - 1)
            new_list.append(letters[position])
        else:
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list

while letter_counter > 0:
    number_of_es.append(inp_list.count("e"))
    print(number_of_es)
    letter_counter -= 1
    inp_list = shift_list(inp_list)
    print(inp_list)
    print(letter_counter)
```

Comment: I have to exit this way because it enters an infinite loop

Comment: Sorry, my answer should solve your problem now.